# How to clone menus in Drupal?

Tags: 7

I want to implement conditional menus, where different options appear depending on the user's role.

In [Display Different Menu links an content depending upon user role or user logged in](https://www.drupal.org/node/1963676), user "nevets" suggested making multiple menus each with the appropriate links, and then restricting the visibility of a particular menu by user role.

In my case, the different menus might share a lot of links, so I thought of cloning the links to avoid having to re-enter them when making the second and subsequent menus.

I found the [Menu clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_clone)? module, but the project page warns:

> **D7: This module is still in beta and is a complete rewrite of the original port.** It is never recommended to use beta versions on a production environment. Please keep a backup of your database to avoid problems later on.

How can I achieve this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be professional, use  Menu clone module all right. Simply do it on development copy of client's site.

It's never a good idea to use beta modules on production site *without testing* them on devel and stage, but if you do test and they work for your particular site, it's usually safe*. And if all you need are cloned menus, you can use it and then uninstall before stage -> production migration so it will never even appear on your production server.

---

* As safe as your tests were good.

Comment: Aha, i never saw it this way: just as a helper module...

Comment: @Volker always glad to provide alternative point of view. The more of them you have, the better chance you will make good, informed decision :)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that cloning menu's would fit your use case, this sound more like the job for [Context Reaction Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_reaction_menus).

Cloning Menus becomes cumbersome when you have to remove or omit a menu link in **all** menus if it ever becomes irrelevant.

It's probably better to set the context for specific link (i.e. hide this link for Scenario B,C and E). This is especially useful if you want to present different menu content for different parts of the website.

Comment: +1 for pointing alternative approach, but are you sure that module with only 166 installations and last release in 2013 can be considered well tested and safe to use?

Comment: Some of the more niche context modules are sub-1000 installs but are the best and most useful of them.

After all. these are utility modules based on Context which has 1,491,578 downloads and is well tested. These submodules simply do very specific use cases for context - such as exactly what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module may help to finetune your content (nodes), and their corresponding menu items. For any node for which you want a menu item to be shown to selected roles only (no matter in which menu), just use the Content Access rules to the appropriate roles. For those who do not have that role, the corresponding menu item will not be shown.

You can set such access for an entire content type, or for individual nodes. Which implies other possible options to implement what you're trying to do. Not sure if it applies in your case, but you could imagine using multiple content types (with corresponding content access settings), so that based on the content type you use to create a node, it is yes/no shown to specific roles in your menu block. Your content editors would probably love such an easy rule to dynamically change the menu content also.

If the menu items relate to views, then set the views access rules for each view also. Again, only those who have access to the view, will have a menu item that shows up.

**Note**: True, the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module only has a **Beta** version for D7, but right now there are over 70K users using this version. Therefor I think "Beta" is not a valid release qualifier for that version anymore, because *+70K users can't be wrong*, right?

Comment: Content Access is pretty mature. Beta and RC modules are fine as long as they are mature.